# All element of List is the same after adding in java

Tags: java, list, element, addition

I recently got a mistake in my java project because of my misunderstanding. I have the following code:

```
 Post post = new Post(); // Post is my custom class
 List<Post> list = new ArrayList<Post>();
 for( int i = 0; i < num; i++){
      post.setTitle( TITLE[i] ); //TITLE[] is a array of String.
      list.add(post);
 }
```

And after that all of element in the List list is the same and equal to the post with the title TITLE[num-1].
I know I got a misunderstanding in this problem because when I put the contructor

```
 Post post = new Post();
```

inside the loop for, every thing is Ok. But anybody can explain this for me, please? Thank you very much.

Comment: What does `new Post();` do? If you don't have it, what does `list.add(post);` mean?

Answer (score 6):

You have just created one `Post` object, so in the lines

```
post.setTitle( TITLE[i] ); //TITLE[] is a array of String.
list.add(post);
```

you are just changing the title of that `Post` and adding it to the `list`. At the end, you will have only *one* `Post` in the `list`, but multiple times.

**Why?** Because in fact, objects are references to locations in memory, so you are adding the same reference (same location) on each iteration.

**How can you solve it?** You can create a new object on each iteration:

```
for( int i = 0; i < num; i++){
    Post post = new Post();
    post.setTitle( TITLE[i] );
    list.add(post);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a single Post. Inside your loop, you're setting the name of that same Post over and over again, then adding it to a List. Each element of the List points to the same instance of Post, which you've renamed a bunch of times.

Putting the Post post = new Post() line inside the loop creates a *new* instance of Post, assigns it a name, and adds that *new* instance to the List. Now each index of the List points to a different instance of Post, each with a different name.

Think about it this way: pretend you have a dog named Bingo. You take a picture of the dog, then add that picture to a photo album. You then rename that dog to Fido. You take another picture of that same dog, then add that picture to the photo album. Repeat this process 100 times. Do you have 100 pictures of different dogs with different names? Or do you have 100 pictures of the same dog with whatever name you gave it last?

Recommended reading: http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryCups.jsp
And its follow-up: http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp

Answer (score 2):

`post` is an instance of the object `Post`.

What you are doing in `post.setTitle(...)` is modifying `post` and storing a reference to it in the list. All the elements in the list are references to the same `Post` object, so if you modify it, all the elements in the list will change.

If you want to store diferent `Post` items, you need to create different `Post` items each time.

Comment: Obligatory note: This is because in Java, all object variables actually store a reference to the object (and the object data is stored somewhere in the heap). This is not the same as pass by reference, since the reference itself is copied when passed into methods.

Comment: @jpmc26 Exactly, Java passes object references by value, which is... kinda confusing to explain, actually.

Comment: @RobertoIzquiredo It doesn't help that some professors teach it wrong. >_> I once had a professor (not for a class where this was covered, but who was teaching one during the same semester) with whom I got into a discussion about it, and at the end of the discussion, she admitted that what she had taught was wrong and that I was right, but she wasn't going to teach it correctly because of the students' "limited understanding." The simplest way of explaining it I have is to refer to the "can't swap variable values by calling another method" example.

Comment: @jpmc26 It's true that a lot of people has problems with Objects & references in Java, but thats just bad teaching =/

Answer (score 0):

Think of a class as a cookie cutter and memory as dough. Every time you call a constructor, you stamp out some of the memory into a shape. This is an object instance.

If you only call the constructor once, you only have one instance of the object. Every time through the loop, you place a pointer to that instance in the collection. At the end of the loop, you have all of these pointers to the same object instance.

When you move the constructor into the loop, every time through the loop, you create a new object instance. You store a pointer to that instance in the list. Now, at the end of the loop, you have one object instance for every pointer in your list.